# Private ways of sharing + synchronizing Dev (Web + Android) project?

Tags: android, web, version-control, sharing

I am currently part of 5 person dev team but our members are in different countries. Until now all the dev projects I have worked on were in the university with local teams and we would just share the project over Google Drive and work on it that way. This has worked for us so far but now for different reasons I would like to try to things differently with this new project.

I have a 4 year old computer lying around which I would like to use as a server and to store the project centrally on this server with some sort of VCS solution as well. I want to use this computer as I would like to stay away from all the public cloud based solutions out there.

I would appreciate all suggestions on how I can use that computer and configure it in a way that would best suit our needs. Thanks

Comment: You're using Google Drive to synchronize code projects? Setup a Github account.

Comment: I was. Is it possible to setup a private github account on my private server.

Comment: You can setup private repos on github

Comment: @GilMoshayof you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using systems like Google Drive or Dropbox to synchronise code files with your team mates. These systems do nothing to prevent teammates from overriding each-others code (if they happen to work on the same file), and provide very weak tracking methods.

There are many other systems out there which can be used for that. My favourite is **Github**. You can setup a private repository there, and share it with whoever you want. You can also make some of your repos public. I would recommend you do this where you can, since it allows people anywhere to use your code, and even offer improvements. In addition, if you consider yourself a professional programmer, a rich public Github account can make an impressive portfolio for potential employers or investors.

Using a system like Github allows you to create branches off your main code so multiple people can easily work on the same code files, and provides advanced tools to track what work was done on which files, when and by whom.

In addition, your repos in Github are hosted by Github, removing the need to rely on your own server which is generally a bad idea - what would happen if that specific machine would crash? All your work would be lost.

I would recommend reading up more on the matter:

[Github Guide](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)
[Git-flows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

There are also several clients applications which work with Github. My favourite client is [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), but there are others out there too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gil, I have been reading up on Github and it seems to be exactly what i need